# boost serialization switching from binary_archive to polymorphic_archive

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

Is it possible to use a `polymorphic_binary_iarchive` to deserialize an object serialized with `binary_oarchive`?

My library has been written using binary archives for all the serialisation methods (as well as EOS portable archives). This results in overloaded `serialize` methods everywhere, significant code bloat and link time cost. I'd like to switch to polymorphic archive methods to reduce the number of exposed `serialize` methods and facilitate easy use of other archives (in particular XML). However, I would also like to maintain backwards compatibility with already serialized data.

`polymorphic_binary_iarchive` seems to work *usually*, but there is at least one case where it fails: `vector.hpp` changes the method of serialization depending on `use_array_optimization`, which for binary archives is set for any type that `is_bitwise_serializable`. So types that contain `vector<size_t>` fail to deserialize.

I'm tempted to try to specialize `use_array_optimization` for `polymorphic_binary_iarchive` (and the `oarchive` similarly). Is there any reason this would not work, or any other reasons why this is just *A Bad Idea*(TM)?

**Edit**

I tried that specialization:

```
struct use_array_optimization_in_polymorphic_archive {
  template <class T>
  struct apply : public boost::serialization::is_bitwise_serializable< T > {};
};

namespace boost {
namespace serialization {

template <>
struct use_array_optimization<boost::archive::polymorphic_iarchive> {
  template <class ValueType>
  struct apply : boost::mpl::apply1<
    use_array_optimization_in_polymorphic_archive,
    BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME boost::remove_const<ValueType>::type>::type {};
};

}}
```

But it doesn't work because `array.hpp` then expects `polymorphic_iarchive` to implement `load_array`, which is only implemented for a `basic_binary_iprimitive`.

I'm also concerned that this will change behaviour for all `polymorphic_iarchive` implementations, not just the `polymorphic_binary_iarchive`. More thought required...

**Edit2**

Herefollows some code by way of demonstration. Toggle POLY_ON to use the polymorphic archive to deserialize; this works for doubles. Toggle VEC_ON to use vectors, demonstrating the problem. **NB:** I haven't yet double checked that this is exactly the same problem, but I'm reasonably sure it is. **NNB:** This is using Boost 1.59.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>

// #define POLY_ON
#ifdef POLY_ON
#include <boost/archive/polymorphic_binary_iarchive.hpp>
#else
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#endif

// #define VEC_ON
#ifdef VEC_ON
#include <vector>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#endif

class bank_balance {
 private:
  friend class boost::serialization::access;
  template <class archive>
  void serialize(archive& ar, const unsigned int version) {
    ar & date_;
    ar & rate_;
  }

#ifdef VEC_ON
  std::vector<double> date_;
  std::vector<double> rate_;
#else
  double date_;
  double rate_;
#endif

 public:
  bank_balance() : date_(0) {}
  bank_balance(
#ifdef VEC_ON
      std::vector<double> date, std::vector<double> rate
#else
      double date, double rate
#endif
  )
    : date_(date), rate_(rate)
  {}

  bool operator==(const bank_balance& other) const {
    return date_ == other.date_ && rate_ == other.rate_;
  }
};

int main() {
  std::ofstream ofs("bank_balance.ser");

#ifdef VEC_ON
  const bank_balance balance({45367, 45369}, {5.6, 2.43});
#else
  const bank_balance balance(45367, 5.6);
#endif

  {
    boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(ofs);
    oa << balance;
  }

  bank_balance balance2;
  {
    std::ifstream ifs("bank_balance.ser");
#ifdef POLY_ON
    boost::archive::polymorphic_binary_iarchive ia(ifs);
#else
    boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(ifs);
#endif
    ia >> balance2;
  }

  if (balance == balance2) std::cout << "ok\n";
  else std::cout << "dammit\n";

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to use a polymorphic_binary_iarchive to deserialize an object serialized with binary_oarchive?

Short answer: yes.

The only difference is the call-site interface here.

### EDIT

Perhaps, unintentionally, this "promise" was broken when they introduced optimized serialization for POD containers.

Here's my analysis, with [`yours.cpp`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/15467902/) from your question, and [`mine.cpp`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/15467899/) as edited below:

```
{ 
    std::ofstream ofs("bank_balance.ser");
#ifdef POLY_ON
    boost::archive::polymorphic_binary_oarchive oa(ofs);
#else
    boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(ofs);
#endif
    oa << balance;
}
```

I compile all flavours with the following command line:

```
for src in yours mine; do for a in {,-DPOLY_ON}\ {,-DVEC_ON}; do time g++ $a -O2 -std=c++11 $src.cpp -lboost_{system,serialization} -o "$src${a//[D _]/}.exe"; done; done
```

Which results in `mine.exe`,  `mine-POLYON.exe`,  `mine-POLYON-VECON.exe`,  `mine-VECON.exe`,  `yours.exe`,  `yours-POLYON.exe`,  `yours-POLYON-VECON.exe` and  `yours-VECON.exe`. Running them:

```
(set -x; for a in ./*.exe; do $a; done)
```

Results in

```
+ ./mine.exe
ok: true

+ ./mine-POLYON.exe
ok: true

+ ./mine-POLYON-VECON.exe
ok: true

+ ./mine-VECON.exe
ok: true

+ ./yours.exe
ok

+ ./yours-POLYON.exe
ok

+ ./yours-POLYON-VECON.exe
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
  what():  vector::_M_default_append

+ ./yours-VECON.exe
ok
```

Note that all combinations are fine if you write using the same archive implementation as while reading. You're also right that sadly `./yours-POLYON-VECON.exe` is the only one to break. I think this is unintentional but your hunch could be spot on:

> [doc](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/serialization/doc/archive_reference.html#polymorphic)
>
> Note that the concept of polymophic archives is ***fundamentally incompatible with the serialization of new types that are marked "primitive"*** by the user with:
>
> ```
>   BOOST_CLASS_IMPLEMENTATION(my_primitive_type, boost::serialization::primitive_type)
> ```
>
> Code to implement serialization for these types is instantiated "on the fly" in the user's program. But this conflicts with the whole purpose of the polymorphic archive. An attempt to serialize such a primitive type will result in a compilation error since the common polymorhic interface is static and cannot instantiate code for a new type.

It looks like the vector optimization path might be sharing one of these code paths.

### RECOMMENDATION

I'd recommend making a conversion tool to convert old format files to the new format. You can read using the non-polymorphic iarchive and write using the polymorphic archive. That, of course, means you'll have to compile both approaches for this release, but

- it doesn't have to be baked into the main executable(s) - only the conversion tools does need the "old" method
- the conversion tool will not have to be versioned, it stays the same for all future releases; this means you can stop building new versions and drop the required extra code.

Comment: Thanks. Yes we are also using the EOS portable archive (so I am trying to use `eos::polymorphic_portable_iarchive`, which appears to be working). Boost version is 1.51, and there are no changes to compiler or flags. All I have done is replace `serialize` (and associated methods) that were taking conrete archive types with the same taking only `polymorphic_iarchive` and `polymorphic_oarchive`. Would you be able to link to the breaking change you mention?

Comment: There's a partial list of cases http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/serialization/src/basic_archive.cpp. The release notes don't mention anything that looks relevant since v. 1.48

Comment: After further consideration (and 2 subsequent Edits to my question), I'm not convinced the "Short answer: yes" is accurate. It looks to me like it will require a Merry Old Jig(TM).

Comment: I've analyzed your samples. I think my short answer was "right by design". But in practice it looks like this optimization has thwarted the design promise a bit. I've added my analysis & recommendation to the answer. If by "Merry Old Jig™" you mean "Conversion Tool" then I think we agree :)

Comment: The recommendation is a good one, but not for my specific deliverable. The serialization code is strewn through types in multiple DLLs. It would entail effectively baking all those DLLs into a conversion tool and bundling the tool with the library. However, I have found that I can specialize the boost::archive::load functions for polymorphic_iarchive and hop across to an implementation where I can downcast to the polymorphic_binary_iarchive and from there summon suitable functions. There are downsides, but these seem manageable. I'll update when I have it working. Appreciate any comments.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old topic, but I've been fighting with this precise problem, and think I have found a good solution.

The core of the problem is that polymorphic archives never get dispatched to use the optimized load/save versions in boost/serialization/vector.hpp. How I fixed this was to overload those dispatch functions for the polymorphic archive types like this:

```
namespace boost::serialization
{
   template<class U, class Allocator>
   inline void load(boost::archive::polymorphic_iarchive& ar, std::vector<U, Allocator>& t, const unsigned int file_version)
   {
      using use_optimized = boost::has_trivial_constructor<U>::type;
      load(ar, t, file_version, use_optimized());
   }
    
   template<class U, class Allocator>
   inline void save(boost::archive::polymorphic_oarchive& ar, const std::vector<U, Allocator>& t, const unsigned int file_version)
   {
      using use_optimized = boost::has_trivial_constructor<U>::type;
      save(ar, t, file_version, use_optimized());
   }
}
```